# In codeigniter 3, extends not working on "application\libraries\MY_Log.php" from "system\core\Log.php"

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

In codeigniter 3, extends not working on `application\libraries\MY_Log.php` from `system\core\Log.php`.

Codeigniter 3.1.2 provide Log.php in core folder not in library. so i have added manually "Log.php" in "system\libraries\Log.php". its seems working fine.
but system\core\Log.php not working.

I am not able to extends it.

```
class MY_Log extends CI_Log {
```

Comment: Whats is the error??

Comment: Please share the error you are getting.

Comment: You shouldn't change files/structure under system. Make it under application directory. Try to use `APPPATH.'core/MY_Log.php'` location.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'CI_Log' not found in  ... application\libraries\MY_Log.php